# Handling wildcards in a string SQL Audit

Tags: sql, replace, substring, audit

I am writing a query that takes the Last Names from a SQL 2008 Audit File and can compare them against another table.

I used this query to get the LastName from the Audit file:

```
select SUBSTRING(TempLastName,CHARINDEX('LastName like ',TempLastName)+14,LEN(TempLastName)) 
from (
select REPLACE((SUBSTRING(statement, CHARINDEX('LastName like ', statement )     ,
(LEN(statement)))),'''','') as TempLastName from #AuditTemp where statement     
like '%LastName like%' and server_principal_name not like 'xxxadminxxx') as a
```

and 'statement' (from above) comes from the Audit file.  It is simply the query that was run that triggered the Audit.  It will look similar to:

```
select lastname from Database.dbo.table where LastName like 'Smith'
```

My query can successfully get a name out, but only under one condition, if the query coming in is built a specific way.  I am having a hard time changing the query to work for all instances.

So where it breaks, is that if a person is searched by wildcards.  This obviously breaks my SubString part of my query and again, I am unsure how to work out this solution.  For example, if they used where LastName like '%Smith', or '%Smith%' etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you need to replace % with '' which will ignore all these wildcard queries. Just enclose another Replace(,'%',''). Like this:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(TempLastName, CHARINDEX('LastName like ', TempLastName) + 14, LEN(TempLastName))
FROM (SELECT
  REPLACE(REPLACE((SUBSTRING(statement, CHARINDEX('LastName like ', statement),
  (LEN(statement)))), '''', ''), '%', '') AS TempLastName
FROM #AuditTemp
WHERE statement
LIKE '%LastName like%'
AND server_principal_name NOT LIKE 'xxxadminxxx') AS a;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This gets me closer to the right path.  Ill have to do the same for other wildcards so this query may get out of hand in a hurry :)